# How can I merge 2 edges in python

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have one problem is how to merge 2 edges in directed graph like picture below. For example: edge a,b and b,a. Then I make adjacency matrix, i am using networkx. In networkx have some method to merge? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Could you be clearer on the merging conditions? From what I understand from the image, you have a directed graph and are trying to produce an undirected graph which has the same nodes, and has an edge between two nodes iff there was at least a directed edge between those nodes in the original graph. If that is correct, you can simply use networkx's [`to_undirected`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.to_undirected.html).